# Object not returning all elements with doctrine

Tags: php, foreach, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I am dumping this loop variable **$document_id**:

```
foreach($onboarding_data as $user_id => $document_id) {
   var_dump($document_id);
}
```

and returns an array of elements like it's supposed to:

```
array(4) { [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "1" }
```

But when I use ***$document_id*** to create an object query

```
foreach($onboarding_data as $user_id => $document_id) {
    $documents = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Documents')->findById($document_id);
    var_dump($documents);
}
```

My object only contains the results of the first key of the array

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(Entities\Documents)#481 (3) { ["id":protected]=> int(1) ["documents":protected]=> string(8) "Form I-9" ["url":protected]=> string(7) "I-9.pdf" } }
```

What happens with the other keys [2], [3], [4]? Why aren't they showing in the object I created?

Comment: All of the values in the array that you're passing in are the same -- `1`. I.e., you're basically saying, "Give me documents 1, 1, 1, and 1."

Comment: @AlexHowansky Oh I see! How would I look for the key of the array instead of the value?

Comment: `array_keys($document_id)`

Comment: @AlexHowansky Sorry I'm having issues with the syntax. Would it be $documents = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Documents')->findBy( array_keys($document_id)); ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but this

```
array(4) { [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Looks like the output of the whole array while you are printing an element of the array

Check this to see the difference of data output with what you have

```
$a = array();
array_push($a,"test 1");
array_push($a,"test 2");
var_dump($a);
echo("<br/>");
foreach($a as $user_id => $document_id) {
   var_dump($document_id);
}
```

Output is

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "test 1" [1]=> string(6) "test 2" }
string(6) "test 1" string(6) "test 2"
```

I suspect your array to have only one element (and that element is an array of 4 elements you are printing). This is why you have only one output instead of 4.

So I think this is your main issue, but what @Alex Howansky says in the comment seems to be true even if this is not your main issue here. If you pass your data correctly you will have 4 times the same data printed.

Comment: The first part is printing correctly, the key is different while the value is the same. I want to create my object that will give me the documents that the Id matches the key of the array im passing